# were did the Symfony Legacy/RecursiveValidator go?

Tags: php, symfony, validation

im updating a project from sf2.6->3.4 + php5.6->php7.1 and its going pretty well right now. i cant figure out what happend to my dependency injection "@validator"... before the update we used the LegacyValidator and injected it via "@validator" to the constructor. now after the update "@validator" is a instance of TraceableValidator and not the "LegacyValidator(after rework: RecursiveValidator)" which triggers error on nearly every route.

i checked the container and installed the symfony plugin for phpstorm to actually get autocompletion on dependency injection - but nothing else then "@validator" (debug.validator/TraceableValidator) is found.

how am i supposed to rework this to get the right validator in my services?

the LegacyValidator was deprecated and it was suggested to use the RecursiveValidator instead... i did all that before updating but now... help and explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you read this https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#autowiring-by-default-use-type-hint-instead-of-service-id ?

Comment: so im forced to refactor for autowire/autoconfig - was hoping to skip that for a while ? we have 1000+ fully wired services...  but ok whatsoever - thanks for the link - so i can get the RecusiveValidator trough TypeHinting it and removing the actual "hard"-wire in services.yml

Comment: No you don't have to. If you don't want to use autowiring yet, you can try to use an alias https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html#aliasing

Comment: figured it out, thanks